# Python 3.10 match case with arbitrary conditions

Tags: python, python-3.x, switch-statement

Is there any way to use **arbitrary conditions** on cases in a Python 3.10+ **match statement** or is it necessary to fall back on if-then control structures?
Clarification: an arbitrary condition might be a function with `myVariable` as argument that evaluates to type bool.

The constraint here is to **keep the order of the cases** (since the first few cases appear extremely often and performance is essential).

```
match myVariable:
  case 'a': ...
  case someConditionOnMyVariable: ...
  case someOtherConditionOnMyVariable: ...
  case 'bb': ...
  case _: ...
```

Comment: There is no `switch` statement in Python 3.10.

Comment: Are you talking about the new `match` statement?

Comment: sorry, it is the `match` statement

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you mean the `match` statement, you could probably use [a wildcard pattern](https://docs.python.org/3.10/reference/compound_stmts.html#wildcard-patterns) with [a guard](https://docs.python.org/3.10/reference/compound_stmts.html#guards) for your arbitrary condition:

```
def check(x):
    return len(x) % 3 == 0


def test(my_var):
    match my_var:
        case 'a':
            print("aa!")
        case _ if check(my_var):
            print("yup!")
        case _:
            print("no match")


test("a")
test("bbb")
test("blop")
```

prints out

```
aa!
yup!
no match
```

Comment: Wildcard works only in that way by changing the order which I do not want to.
Of course I could nest match in order to achieve this but that would somehow defeat the purpose of the match statement since it would not be any different then using if-structures.

Comment: What do you mean with "changing the order"? Clearly the order of the case branches is honored here.

Comment: Your solution is correct. I though you would have to put `case _ if ...` to the end of the list of cases. It turns out that it also works if you add a regular case like `case 'b'` between `case _ if ...` and `case _:`

Comment: The flow is explained [in the `match` docs](https://docs.python.org/3.10/reference/compound_stmts.html#overview) – the cases are evaluated in isolation and in sequence. (In fact, `match` compiles down into a series of `if`s, if you look at the `dis` output for it.)